How do I make an event input system with GLFW?
I am trying to make a little game engine with OpenGL and GLFW. I've tried to get inputs to work and they do! But it's very clunky because you need a reference to the window object meaning it's not convenient to handle inputs from scripts other than main.cpp.
#include<iostream>
#include "inputHeader.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

bool GetKey(GLFWwindow* window, int KeyCode)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, KeyCode) == GLFW_PRESS)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool GetKeyDown(GLFWwindow* window, int key) {
    static bool keyPreviouslyPressed[GLFW_KEY_LAST + 1] = { false }; 

    if (glfwGetKey(window, key) == GLFW_PRESS && !keyPreviouslyPressed[key]) {
        keyPreviouslyPressed[key] = true;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

//input activation from main.cpp

if (GetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_SPACE))
{
    //do stuff
}

How can I make it so that you don't need a reference to the window object to handle input?

But it's very clunky because you need a reference to the window object meaning it's not convenient to handle inputs from scripts other than main.cpp The part you call clunky makes for better code design. The alternative is using global variables which are not usually good design. With all of this said I think your problem stems from the fact that you are using lots of free functions and not classes. With classes you can have a GLFWwindow* as a class member variable of your objects and not need to pass it around so much.

Well you can look into Behavioral Design Patterns  [1] in your case I believe the observer pattern would be sufficient. Luckily your prompt, is similar to this post  [2] using callbacks providing some event handling mechanisms.
GLFWkeyfun glfwSetKeyCallback (GLFWwindow * window, GLFWkeyfun  callback)

https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/behavioral-patterns
How to glfwSetKeyCallback for different classes?
https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__input.html#ga1caf18159767e761185e49a3be019f8d

